# POI check cell is whether empty or not?

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, npoi

Well, i'm trying to read cell from excel sheet. And if the cell has no value or empty it will return false. I tried "`null`" (`sheet.getrow(a).getcell(b) == null` and `sheet.getrow(a).getcell(b).celltype == celltype.Blank`) but when cell has blank spaces or its filled with color it returns `false`.

Thanks, i've been stuck with this for days. (if you need code i can edit it).

Answer (score 5):

Whether a cell is "empty" depends partly on whether the cell actually exists (i.e. not null), what type of cell it is (string / number / blank, etc.) and what value is in the cell, depending on its type.  I would make some extension methods to make this determination easier.  You can tweak them to work however you want.  For example, if you consider a cell with no value but filled with color to be non-empty, you can add a check for that inside the `IsNullOrEmpty` method.

```
public static class NpoiExtensions
{
    public static bool IsCellNullOrEmpty(this ISheet sheet, int rowIndex, int cellIndex)
    {
        if (sheet != null)
        {
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex);
            if (row != null)
            {
                ICell cell = row.GetCell(cellIndex);
                return cell.IsNullOrEmpty();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this ICell cell)
    {
        if (cell != null)
        {
            // Uncomment the following lines if you consider a cell 
            // with no value but filled with color to be non-empty.
            //if (cell.CellStyle != null && cell.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor != null)
            //    return false;

            switch (cell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.String:
                    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.StringCellValue);
                case CellType.Boolean:
                case CellType.Numeric:
                case CellType.Formula:
                case CellType.Error:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        // null, blank or unknown
        return true;
    }
}
```

With these methods in place, your code becomes much simpler:

```
if (sheet.IsCellNullOrEmpty(a, b))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cell at row " + a + " column " + b + " is empty.");
}
```